# chart is not align in horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have below code which shows charts in output. I'm trying to show more than one charts in a column which should stack horizontally.

If I copy this code any where in the body tag it shows vertical stack of charts. Likewise other three chart follows same code only element id changes. The chart should arrange horizontally not vertically. What goes wrong?

[image: The view:]

My code:

```
          <div class="container">
            <div class="raw">
            <!-- Chart wrapper -->
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <canvas id="chart1"></canvas></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <canvas id="chart2"></canvas></div>
            <div class=col-md-2>
            <canvas id="chart3"></canvas></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <canvas id="chart4"></canvas></div>

          </div>
          </div>
        <script>
         var mylabel=["A","B"];
         var mydata = [10,20];
         var ctx = document.getElementById('chart1');

         var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         type: 'horizontalBar',
data: {
         labels: mylabel,
         datasets: [{
         label: '# of Votes',
         data: mydata,
         backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        barThickness: 10
        }]
         },
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
        barPercentage: 0.5,
        barThickness: 6,
        maxBarThickness: 8,
        minBarLength: 2,
        gridLines: {
            offsetGridLines: false
        }
    }]
    }
}

    });
      </script>
```

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1htDKQJGbogG1VzcLDWnAaBu9xFevauk_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you make it running whatever you have in your above post, using Stackoverflow snippet?

Comment: What if you change xAxes in the options to yAxes?